# Proper x-axis for Highcharts stack group column

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, stacked-chart

I'm trying to develop a chart that visualizes data using 1 measurement and 3 dimensions. I put one dimension on the x-axis, one as stack and one as list of series.

HighCharts has the stacked-grouped-column chart that I use as basis. See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b72e0vh4/3/).

```
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        color: '#ff4400',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        stack: '2014'
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        color: '#44ff00',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
        stack: '2014'
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        color: '#ff4400',
        data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
        showInLegend: false,
        stack: '2015'
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
        color: '#44ff00',
        showInLegend: false,
        stack: '2015'
    }]
```

[image]

I would like to be able to display the **stack name on a second level x-axis**. I know of the [group-plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories), but that does not seems to work together with stacks.

Any hints?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It might not be the best solution (so please keep 'm coming), but I now fake a dataseries.

See [jsfiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/b72e0vh4/5/)

```
  xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
               {
            categories: ['2014', '2015', '2014', '2015', '2014', '2015','2014', '2015', '2014', '2015'],
                   opposite: true
        }],        
  series: [{
        name: 'John',
        color: '#ff4400',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        stack: '2014',

    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        color: '#44ff00',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
        stack: '2014',

    }, {
        name: 'John',
        color: '#ff4400',
        data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
        showInLegend: false,
        stack: '2015'
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
        color: '#44ff00',
        showInLegend: false,
        stack: '2015'
    }, {
        name: '',
        data: [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0],
        showInLegend: false,
        stack: '2015',
        xAxis: 1            
    }]
```

Result:
[image]

### Update

Fiddled around with fake axis labels: http://jsfiddle.net/b72e0vh4/8/
[image]