# Highcharts Grouped stack x.axis name + category name

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get my highcharts graph to look like this or similar to this.

[image]

I have tried to use groupped category addon for highcharts, but it down not seem to work well with stack option.

sample in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/02ey1hbr/7/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
                    rotation: -0,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        align: 'Right',
                    }

                },
        categories: [{
                name: "Case A",
                categories: ["Male", "Female"]
            }, {
                name: "Case B",
                categories: ["Male", "Female"]
            }]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'x-axis'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },

    series: [{
        name: 'x',
        data: [5,3,4,5],
                stack: 'StackA'
    }, {
        name: 'y',
        data: [3,5,4,5],
        stack: 'StackA'
        },{
        name: 'x',
        data: [5,3,4,5],
                stack: 'StackB'
    }, {
        name: 'y',
        data: [3,5,4,5],
        stack: 'StackB'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within my project, using stacks allows me to get better control over the 12 data sets in a series that is split into 2 stacks. Example in jsfiddle is a smaller version to get the proof of concept working and better interact with community. Stacks also make the code much easier to maintain.

Using: [Proper x-axis for Highcharts stack group column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028330/proper-x-axis-for-highcharts-stack-group-column?rq=1) as a reference, i was able to modify my example to: http://jsfiddle.net/02ey1hbr/11/ and achieve a working example with stacks. Its not perfect but really close to.

[image]

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: [{
          categories: ["Case A", "Case B","Case C", "Case D"],
          labels: {
            rotation: -90,
            x: -60,
            style: {
              fontSize: '10px',
              align: 'Right',
            }
          },
          tickWidth: 1,
          tickLength: 60,
    },
    {
       categories: ['Male', 'Female','Male', 'Female','Male', 'Female','Male', 'Female'],
       opposite: false,
        labels: {
          rotation: 0,
          x: 60,
          style: {
            fontSize: '10px',
            align: 'Right',
          }
        },
        tickWidth: 0,
    }],
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'x-axis'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
    series: [{
        name: 'x',
        data: [1,8,9,16],
                stack: 'StackA'
    }, {
        name: 'y',
        data: [1,7,10,15],
        stack: 'StackA'
        },{
        name: 'x',
        data: [3,6,11,14],
                stack: 'StackB'
    }, {
        name: 'y',
        data: [4,5,12,13],
        stack: 'StackB'
        },
         {
           name: '',
           data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
           showInLegend: false,
           stack: 'StackB',
           xAxis: 1            
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To display bar the way you want, you need to get rid of the `stack` property from all series. Why do you want to preserve them? They are used for dividing series into groups. I also corrected position of labels using x property.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Ccolumn%3E.stack
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.x

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sjtdgq9L/

Answer (score 0):

Change your series to:-

series: [{
        name: 'x',
        data: [5,3,4,5]
    }, {
        name: 'y',
        data: [3,5,4,5]
        },{
        name: 'x',
        data: [5,3,4,5]
    }, {
        name: 'y',
        data: [3,5,4,5]
        }
    ]

[image]

Comment: Without a stack, it works, although my main data is based on stacks. I am trying to find a solution to get it work with stacks.

Comment: in your solution you have removed   `stack: 'StackA' & stack: 'StackB'`. Do you have a solution to keep them in, they are required for my data flow.